# CQRS Event with complex types

Tags: .net, events, .net-core, cqrs

So i'm using CQRS in my application. And now i have a event that needs other model/class in it's implementation, just like a valueObject is used for an Entity.

An simple example, I have a user Event, and this event has a propertie called Address, and this address is type of AddressModel.

So how should i call this AddressModel? a valuObject, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with `AddressDpo` where `Dpo` stand for Domain Payload Object.

`Model` is too generic and it's definitely not a `ValueObject` since value objects have behavior that can affects event sourced projection rebuilds if changed. Events should be data structure nothing more. Here is [an article](https://buildplease.com/pages/vos-in-events/) from Nick Chamberlain about this.

DPOs are briefly mentioned in [this article](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/ddd/ddd_and_hexagonal).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, definitely a great choice use DPO